# C# Universal Windows Application How to get time from internet

Tags: c#, datetime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

I'm having trouble with the Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT core as the system clock tends to drift quite significantly over time. I decided to make a program, which would set the system clock back into correct time, which the device would acquire from the internet. I already know how I can set the system clock, but the problem is: How do I acquire precise time from the internet when running C# Universal Windows Application on Windows 10 IoT core?

I have done the following before to acquire time from windows time server on x86 and x64:

```
public static DateTime GetNetworkTime()
{
    //default Windows time server
    const string ntpServer = "time.windows.com";

    // NTP message size - 16 bytes of the digest (RFC 2030)
    var ntpData = new byte[48];

    //Setting the Leap Indicator, Version Number and Mode values
    ntpData[0] = 0x1B; //LI = 0 (no warning), VN = 3 (IPv4 only), Mode = 3 (Client Mode)

    var addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList;

    //The UDP port number assigned to NTP is 123
    var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addresses[0], 123);
    //NTP uses UDP
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

   //Stops code hang if NTP is blocked
   socket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;     

   socket.Send(ntpData);
   socket.Receive(ntpData);
   socket.Close();

   //Offset to get to the "Transmit Timestamp" field (time at which the reply 
  //departed the server for the client, in 64-bit timestamp format."
  const byte serverReplyTime = 40;

  //Get the seconds part
  ulong intPart = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplyTime);

  //Get the seconds fraction
  ulong fractPart = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplyTime + 4);

  //Convert From big-endian to little-endian
  intPart = SwapEndianness(intPart);
  fractPart = SwapEndianness(fractPart);

  var milliseconds = (intPart * 1000) + ((fractPart * 1000) / 0x100000000L);

  //**UTC** time
  var networkDateTime = (new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).AddMilliseconds((long)milliseconds);

  return networkDateTime.ToLocalTime();
}

// stackoverflow.com/a/3294698/162671
static uint SwapEndianness(ulong x)
{
    return (uint) (((x & 0x000000ff) << 24) +
               ((x & 0x0000ff00) << 8) +
               ((x & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) +
               ((x & 0xff000000) >> 24));
}
```

but it does not work for universal windows applications, as `Dns` and other related classes are not available for use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

Avoid the problem and not use internet time. Instead, use a real time clock integrated circuit like [DS1302](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DS1302).

### Option 2

Use the Windows 10 universal app classes to connect over UDP. They use a [DatagramSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.aspx). Here is some rough code implementing a datagram socket and getting back the response from the time server.

```
private async void ConnectToTimeServer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var socket = new DatagramSocket();
    socket.MessageReceived += SocketMessageReceived;
    await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("time.windows.com"), "123");

    using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream))
    {
        var ntpData = new byte[48];
        ntpData[0] = 0x1B;
        dataWriter.WriteBytes(ntpData);
        await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
    }
}
```

Then the message received event code as follows:

```
private void SocketMessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        using (var reader = args.GetDataReader())
        {
            byte[] response = new byte[48];
            reader.ReadBytes(response);

            YourMethodToParseNetworkTime(response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This helps to solve the problem. It was hard to find anything on this topic on the internet for some reason.

Comment: From my experience, I'd recommend the DS3231 over the 1302. I've found it to be more accurate with significantly less drift.